# Why can't I see the cellular/battery status on my hotspot iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, tethering

[image]

It just looks like this. My Mac isn't receiving that info for some reason.

The phone is iPhone 12 mini, the Mac is MacBook Air M1.

Also, the hotspot doesn't show by itself in the networks list. I need to first enable it on my iPhone. Even tho both devices are connected to the same iCloud account.